# Batch file to xcopy files to folder based on wmic computersystem get model

Tags: batch-file

How do I create a batch file that will copy files to a computer based on the results from "wmic computersystem get model"
If you run this bat you will see that the echo code does not work.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic computersystem get model'
) do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do  set PROD=%%a
) 
REM echo %PROD%

SET /p MODELT=%PROD%

if %MODELT%=="Latitude E6520" (
  echo "This is code-block for computer driver copy code stuff"
) else 
  echo "Nothing to see here!"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. First, you're missing some brackets in the `else` part of the bottom `if` block:

```
) else (
    echo "Nothing to see here!"
)
```

Next, are you sure you want to use the `/p` parameter to `SET`? It will prompt the user for input, with the string that you extracted from WMIC previously as the prompt.

Finally, if you want to compare a variable to a string in a batch file, you need to put double quotes around the variable:

```
if "%MODELT%" == "Latitude E6520"
```

When debugging and printing strings out, I like to do it like this so I can see if there is any spurious whitespace that I need to know about:

```
echo '%PROD%'
```

That way you'll see if there is whitespace at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Here is the update and still the if statement does not work 
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims==" %%a in (
     'wmic computersystem get model'
) do (
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do  set PROD=%%a
) 
if "%PROD%" == "Surface with Windows 8 Pro" (
 echo "This is code-block for computer driver copy code stuff"
) else (
      echo "Nothing to see here!"
    )

SET PROD=%""%

Comment: It works for me, although for me the string that is parsed has two spaces at the end of it, e.g. `"Latitude E6520  "` (I can't seem to coerce SO to put two spaces in there but there should be two). When printing out strings I like to put quotes around them to make sure I can see any spurious whitespace.